# minimal set of words of length n

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Given an alphabet $S={a_1,\cdots,a_m}$, we consider the words of length $n$, $S^n$.

We call two words $b_1b_2\cdots b_n$ and $c_1c_2\cdots c_n$ are connected if $b_i=c_i$ for some $i$.

We consider $P\subseteq S^n$ with the following property: for any $r\in S^n$, there exists $p\in P$ such that $r$ and $p$ are not connected.

What is the minimal size $u_m(n)$ of $P$ to have the wanted property? Is there an explicit construction?

For $m=2$, it shall be $u_2(n)=2^{n}$. What about general $m$?

For $m=3$ and $n=2$, we only need 3 elements, $a_1a_1$, $a_2a_2$ and $a_3a_3$. Because for any $b_1b_2$, there is $i$ such that $b_1\neq a_i$ and $b_2\neq a_i$. Then $a_ia_i$ is not connected with $b_1b_2$. So $u_3(2)=3$.

This seems like a standard error correcting code question.

Comment: Thank you very much! It shall be not connected.

Comment: Yes. Can it be polynomial, even for $m=3$?

Comment: @bof Oh, sorry, I think you are correct. The previous version is wrong.

Comment: @domotorp Thanks!

Comment: domotorp's example generalises to give an upper bound of $n+1$ whenever $m > n$. But $n+1$ is also clearly a lower bound, because if you have $n$ words then you can find a word which is connected to all of them by taking the $i$th letter from the $i$th word. So the problem reduces to the case $m \le n$.

Comment: $u_3(3) = 5$ with e.g. $P = \{aac, aca, caa, bbb, ccc\}$.

Comment: This in a sense is an anti-covering code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_code

Comment: We have bounds: $$\left(\frac{m}{m-1}\right)^n \leq u_m(n) \leq 2^n.$$ Also, for $n<m$, $u_m(n)\leq n+1$.

Comment: $u_3(n)$  for $n=1..6$ are 2, 3, 5, 8, 12, 18. $u_4(n)$ for $n=1..5$ are 2, 3, 4, 7, 10.

Comment: @Max Alekseyev Thank you very much! Would $u_m(n)$ be in the order of $(m/m-1)^n$, up to a polynomial factor? It seems so according to a probabilistic argument.

Comment: In the jargon of graph theory, what you are asking for is the [total domination number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalDominationNumber.html) of the [categorical product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs) (a.k.a. tensor product, direct product, etc. etc. etc.) of $n$ copies of the [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) $K_m$. It might be worthwhile to explore the extensive literature on domination in graphs to see what is known about your question.